# In HTML/CSS how can I make emoji the same size as the text?

Tags: html, css, emoji

On my web page I have a popup image in a series of nested divs. At the top div I have a title. While the higher resolution of this image is loading, I display an emoji hourglass (⏳) in the title. When completed, I remove the hourglass. When the hourglass is removed, the div with the title text in it gets a little smaller, vertically. How can I have the emoji equal to the size of the text so that it does not make my div any taller?

Here is a code snippet that shows a div with a cyan background color and an emoji. When the button is clicked, the innerHTML is replaced with text without emoji and you can see the vertical size get smaller.

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick =
   () => {document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "This is some text without emoji"};
```

```css
div.textWithEmoji {
    font-size : medium;
    background-color : cyan;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Emoji Size Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Emoji Size Test</h1>

<div class="textWithEmoji" id="div">
    This is some text with emoji ⏳
</div>

<br>

<button id="button" type="button">Remove Emoji</button>

</body>

</html>
```

I don't want to force the div height to a specific value as the font-size is a variable in my page.

I have tried setting the size of the emoji to 75% and that works on Chrome and iOS but there is no guarantee that that will work on every platform.

Any ideas how I can get this to do what I want?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: As you found out there is no garantee it will work everywhere. This might also be a known bug in some browsers and maybe those issues get addressed in the future or not, which is out of your control in both cases. For now you will have to find your own solution. Try the span-with-a-class approach from the existing answers - at least you can adjust the emoji size easily then.

Comment: Note that the height of the `<div>` remains identical with and without the emoji in Firefox Desktop. The issue here may be that emoji lack a standard presentation and each OS or browser is at liberty to display *any* emoji entirely arbitrarily, according to inspiration. When I ran into this issue fairly recently, I ended up using `<svg>` instead of emoji.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set a line-height to your div:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('.textWithEmoji').html("This is some text without emoji")
});
```

```css
div.textWithEmoji {
  font-size: medium;
  background-color: cyan;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Emoji Size Test</h1>

<div class="textWithEmoji" style="font-size:10px;">
  This is some text with emoji ⏳
</div>

<div class="textWithEmoji">
  This is some text with emoji ⏳
</div>

<div class="textWithEmoji" style="font-size:20px;">
  This is some text with emoji ⏳
</div>

<div class="textWithEmoji" style="font-size:30px;">
  This is some text with emoji ⏳
</div>



<button id="button" type="button">Remove Emoji</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the icon inside a `<span>` element that holds the emoji. Like:

```
<p>This is some text with emoji <span class="emoji">⏳</span> </p>
```

Then try to give the `<span>` element some CSS to make it with the same size of the text. Of course this solution is hardcoded. Something like:

```
.emoji {
     font-size: 1vw; // vw, vh, em, rem, px or %
     // OR
     transform: scale(1.25);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in a span, give it a class, and reduce the font-size:

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick =
   () => {document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "This is some text without emoji"};
```

```css
div.textWithEmoji {
    font-size : medium;
    background-color : cyan;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 75%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Emoji Size Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Emoji Size Test</h1>

<div class="textWithEmoji" id="div">
    This is some text with emoji <span class="icon">⏳</span>
</div>

<br>

<button id="button" type="button">Remove Emoji</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in `span` and give `font-size`

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick =
   () => {document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "This is some text without emoji"};
```

```css
div.textWithEmoji {
    font-size : medium;
    background-color : cyan;
}
span { font-size: 12px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Emoji Size Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Emoji Size Test</h1>

<div class="textWithEmoji" id="div">
    This is some text with emoji <span>⏳</span>
</div>

<br>

<button id="button" type="button">Remove Emoji</button>

</body>

</html>
```